# CSS hack for Safari not from Chrome

Tags: css, cross-browser

I'm working on responsive webpage creation and I need to create a piece of CSS that  would apply only in Safari(All devices), CSS properties for height working finr in Chrome. I need CSS hack only for safari. Please, could anyone give in some ideas?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered using java script to detect the browser and based on it applying styles?

Comment: Hi @AntK, Thanks. I used jQuery to detect safari and based on that I applied browser specific styles. ex) var is_safari = /Safari/.test(navigator.userAgent) && /Apple Computer/.test(navigator.vendor);

     if(is_safari) { ...mycode....}

Comment: Can you mark the answer as correct or write your own in detail and mart it as correct. This is for people who will face a similar problem in the future. Thank you.